# RabbitMQ delete a corrupted queue after node crash

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ Version 3.7.21
Erlang Version Erlang 21.3.8.10

My team had 2 nodes hit the memory watermark last night and so I rebuilt the bad nodes but it left some queues in a bad state. I want to clear them out so that we can recreate them.

The stats show NaN for Ready, Unacked, and Total and the stats in queue look like:

[image: queue stats]

It looks like the queue's node is one that no longer exists so unfortunately I can't access it. It's completely gone.

I have tried the following commands:

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'Q = rabbit_misc:r(<<"/">>, queue, <<"QUEUE">>), rabbit_amqqueue:internal_delete(Q).'

rabbitmqctl eval 'Q = {resource, <<"/">>, queue, <<"QUEUE">>}, rabbit_amqqueue:internal_delete(Q).'
```

but get this error:

```
{:undef, [{:rabbit_amqqueue, :internal_delete, [{:resource, "/", :queue, "QUEUE"}], []}, {:erl_eval, :do_apply, 6, [file: 'erl_eval.erl', line: 680]}, {:rpc, :"-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-", 5, [file: 'rpc.erl', line: 197]}]}
```

Which I assume means it's trying to make an RPC call to a node that no longer exists and it fails. This seems crazy to me because not just is the node gone but it has been forgotten from the cluster but still a couple queues remain.

Comment: It looks like .. for you only this is the option .. rabbitmqctl reset , not sure how tedious it will be for you to recreate the configuration but for sure will insure that the node is sane

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee These are all new instances. I killed all previous instances and completely recreated the cluster a machine at a time. So I'm not sure what a rabbitmqctl reset would do that recreating it doesn't

Comment: in case if you are running it on docker , could be using the same volume on the host , did you recreate the volumes in that case.

Comment: Not running on docker, these are brand new EC2 instances with RabbitMQ installed directly on them.

Comment: Did this got resolved...

Comment: Kind of. I ended up renaming my queues which was a pain, but about all I could do with the options available. I'm not planning on doing a complete wipe and rebuild of rabbit for a long time, probably the next major breaking change I'll build a new cluster and migrate all my queues slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are 3 options:

1. Comb through the Mnesia tables and delete the corrupted ones
2. Fully rebuild the cluster and migrate to a new cluster
3. Rename your queues and ignore corrupted ones

We're going to go with Option 3 for now but I'm sure eventually there will be a breaking change in RabbitMQ that will make Option 2 more appealing but for now the quick fix is best for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/VSjzvOUfS3s/m/q8OmFTqACAAJ, the `internal_delete` function in 3.7.x takes two arguments:

> In 3.7.x `rabbit_amqqueue:internal_delete` takes two arguments (acting user name is the second one).

Therefore, the next time you need to delete a queue in a bad state, try

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'Q = {resource, <<"/">>, queue, <<"QUEUE">>}, rabbit_amqqueue:internal_delete(Q, <<"CLI">>).'
```

Comment: I have moved on from the company where this happened so unfortunately won't be able to test it, but thank you for the answer! Maybe it'll help someone else.